# Remove duplicated rows on gridview

Tags: html, mysql, vb.net

Hi There I have the following grid view developed with vb.net and html

[image]

This is the code to fill the gridview

```
 Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim modelo As String = txtModelo.Text
    Dim linha As String = txtLinha.Text
    Dim data As String = txtData.Text
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tempo where timermodelo = @timermodelo and timerlinha = @timerlinha and timerdata = @timerdata")
            Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timermodelo", modelo)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timerlinha", linha)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timerdata", data)
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

My question is, is it possible to remove the duplicated rows on the column Operador, Posto, Linha and Modelo? 
And also how can I form the date to show 'dd-mm-yyyy'?
Actually, I want to merge these values, if they are the same, show just one time
Sorry if it is difficult to understand, if more information is needed let me know
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, I hope this would be useful to someone, I was able to achieve that by following this site https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Remove duplicates** : Why don't you use SqlStatement that return rows without duplication, depending on your Database type '**you did not mention**', if this is achievable in your SqlStatement then this problem is solved.

Format Date in GridView1 cell : Use GridView1_CellFormatting event [ Where your Date ColumnIndex = 4] as follows

```
Private Sub GridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CellFormatting
If Not IsNothing(e.Value) Then
            If e.ColumnIndex().ToString = 4 And IsDate(e.Value) Then
               e.Value = Format(e.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
            End If
         End If
End Sub
```

> I want to merge these values, if they are the same

What values are we talking about here ?

Comment: Hello! My database is mysql and I tried a select with a group by statement but it did not return the result I was looking for. If you notice on the picture, the columns "Operador","Posto","Linha" e "Modelo" have duplicated values, I would like to merge them if they are repeated which I was able to achieve by following this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx. Thanks about the date, I will try that!